# Magento 2 Get Translated String

Tags: magento2.3.1, translate

Is there a way to get translated string in php code?

Something like this:

```
$string = __('something');
foreach ($stores as $store){
 echo $store->getName().': '.$store->getTranslated($string)."\n";
}

\\-- output:  
english: someting
italian: qualcosa
french: quelque chose
```

**EDIT:**
@Vinz suggestion could be a nice workaround but I need to use __() function or prashes won't be collected for dictionary.

in magento 1 I used;

```
$newLocaleCode = Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::XML_PATH_DEFAULT_LOCALE, $storeCode);
$initialEnvironmentInfo = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation')->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeCode);
Mage::getSingleton('core/translate')->setLocale($newLocaleCode)->init(Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_FRONTEND, true);
Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation')->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);
```

so after some research i found this:

```
 /**
  * \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation
  */
 protected $emulation;

public function __construct(\Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation $emulation) {
   $this->emulation = $emulation;
}

/**
 * example function in which we want to emulate a stores environment  
 */
public function example($storeId, $area = 'frontend') {

   //starting the store emulation with area defined for admin
   $this->emulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId, 'adminhtml');

   //you can update or save a product attributes here with correct scope or anything else you want to do, perform some test

   // discard the emulated environment after doing your work
   $this->emulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation();

}
```

at this link:
https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-store-emulation/

This works fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2 - How to translate strings to a specific locale?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/186086/magento-2-how-to-translate-strings-to-a-specific-locale)

Comment: this could be a workaround, but the __() function is missed and phrases won't be collected for dictionary.