# Magento 2 Translation on Ajax Backend Not Working

Tags: magento2, ajax, i18n

I am making ajax request , and I call `__('string to translate')` function on backend. The problem is that translate is not working at all.
My ajax controller is implementing `HttpPostActionInterface` Interface to avoid massive data load. If I use previous way, i.e extending `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action` , the translation is working good, however I don't wan't to extend this huge class. Have anybody got idea why `HttpPostActionInterface` is not working with translations?

I've tried various things, including this [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/186086/magento-2-how-to-translate-strings-to-a-specific-locale) , however nothing seems to be working. I will do translations on frontend side eventually , but this doesn't explain why translations are missed on this interface?

Comment: Can you describe with code what you have try and where that not working.

Comment: I am making simple AJAX request and in backend controller I use `$response['message'] = __('Translated text');` . The problem is that text is translated if I extend controller with `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action` , however it does not when controller is only implementing `HttpPostActionInterface`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use translate js for this:

```
require([
'jquery',
'jquery/ui', 
'mage/translate'
], function($){ 
    $.mage.__('Your text message for translation')
});
```