# How to generate Multi-Language invoice and email

Tags: magento2, email, invoice, order-email, invoice-pdf

I have a multi-language store and I need to generate my invoice in 2 different languages in a PDF and the invoice email should also have both the languages. How can I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have 2 languages in one Invoice PDF, you need to overwrite `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice` and `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Invoice\DefaultInvoice` and implement your custom rendering with your layout

If you want to customize email you can customize all `sales_email_invoice_*` templates and customize `sales_email_order_invoice_items` layout depends on your rules.

Maybe [magento 2 how to translate strings to a specific locale](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/186086/magento-2-how-to-translate-strings-to-a-specific-locale) will be helpful as well

One of alternative is generate Email/PDF content part for one locale and after for another one and glue parts

**Invoice Templates [Added]**

Magento uses 4 templates for invoice emails depends on scenario:

- `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/email/invoice_new.html` - email about new Invoice for customer
- `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/email/invoice_new_guest.html` - email about new Invoice for guest
- `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/email/invoice_update.html` - email about update in Invoice for customer
- `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/email/invoice_update_guest.html` - email about update in Invoice for guest

If you want to customize it in you theme you should place copy of those files in `app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Sales/email/`

If you want to customize templates per store you can use Marketing -> Email Templates feature. Create custom template for each store and specify it in Stores -> Configuration for your store scope

[image: Sales Emails]

Comment: Can you specify which file to override for email content based on store id?

Comment: See **Added** part in answer

Comment: Maybe you may help answer from [Magento 2: Print invoice in multiple languages for the same store](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/356654/magento-2-print-invoice-in-multiple-languages-for-the-same-store)