# Magento 2: Print invoice in multiple languages for the same store

Tags: magento2, multistore, invoice, print, multi-language

I have a multistore. One is in English and the other one is in Arabic. The invoice gets printed in the particular language depending on the store.
I want to print the invoice in English and Arabic **together** for the same store.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the getPdf method `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice` in the following way to generate invoice using all the languages of the website stores in a single pdf.

> ```
> public function getPdf($invoices = [])
> {
>     $storeArray = array();
>     $stores = $this->_storeManager->getStores();
>     foreach ($stores as $store) {
>         array_push($storeArray, $store->getStoreId());
>     }
>     $this->_beforeGetPdf();
>     $this->_initRenderer('invoice');
>
>     $pdf = new \Zend_Pdf();
>     $this->_setPdf($pdf);
>     $style = new \Zend_Pdf_Style();
>     $this->_setFontBold($style, 10);
>
>     foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
>
>         foreach ($storeArray as $key) {
>             $this->_localeResolver->emulate($key);
>             $this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore($key);
>             $invoice->setStoreId($key);
>
>             $page = $this->newPage();
>             $order = $invoice->getOrder();
>             /* Add image */
>             $this->insertLogo($page, $invoice->getStore());
>             /* Add address */
>             $this->insertAddress($page, $invoice->getStore());
>             /* Add head */
>             $this->insertOrder(
>                 $page,
>                 $order,
>                 $this->_scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
>                     self::XML_PATH_SALES_PDF_INVOICE_PUT_ORDER_ID,
>                     \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
>                     $key
>                 )
>             );
>             /* Add document text and number */
>             $this->insertDocumentNumber($page, __('Invoice # ') . $invoice->getIncrementId());
>             /* Add table */
>             $this->_drawHeader($page);
>             /* Add body */
>             foreach ($invoice->getAllItems() as $item) {
>                 if ($item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()) {
>                     continue;
>                 }
>                 /* Draw item */
>                 $this->_drawItem($item, $page, $order);
>                 $page = end($pdf->pages);
>             }
>             /* Add totals */
>             $this->insertTotals($page, $invoice);
>             if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
>                 $this->_localeResolver->revert();
>             }
>         }
>     }
>     $this->_afterGetPdf();
>     return $pdf;
> }
> ```